# Change left menu color

Tags: sharepoint-server, css, navigation

Any ideas how to change the head background color in the left menu for all pages in SharePoint without using SharePoint designer?

Appreciate your help Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To change the background header in the left navigation try to add the following CSS to a file with CSS extension**

```
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > .ms-core-listMenu-root > LI > .ms-core-listMenu-item
{

background-color:lime ! important;
}
```

**To apply this style for all pages within the site without SharePoint Designer**

You can achieve this by setting `Alternate CSS URL` for a specific CSS file by doing the following :

- Open your site> Upload the CSS file with the above style to `Site assets`.
- Go to site setting > Look and Feel > Master Page > at Alternate CSS URL > Select Specify CSS file.> check reset all subsite if you need to apply all subsite below the main site.

[image]

**[Output]**

[image]